# Beautiful Soup find children for particular div

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have am trying to parse a webpage that looks like this with Python->Beautiful Soup:[image]

I am trying to extract the contents of the highlighted td div. Currently I can get all the divs by

```
alltd = soup.findAll('td')

   
for td in alltd:
    print td
```

But I am trying to narrow the scope of that to search the tds in the class "tablebox" which still will probably return 30+ but is more managable a number than 300+.

How can I extract the contents of the highlighted td in picture above?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It is useful to know that whatever elements BeautifulSoup finds within one element still have the same type as that parent element - that is, various methods can be called.

So this is somewhat working code for your example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "tablebox"})

for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all("td", {"class": "align-right"})
    for tag in tdTags:
        print tag.text
```

This will print all the text of all the `td` tags with the class of "align-right" that have a parent `div` with the class of "tablebox".

Comment: In parent loop, tag is 'div' element not the soup element, so I think it would make an error, isn't it? In 'div' element, it doesn't have the method called 'find_all'